# Update a column in table according to another column in same table

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table name xyz which has two columns tc_name and tc_path where tc_path is like /a/b/c/x/tc_name and tc_name is null .I want to insert the values in the column(tc_name) using this tc_path column values.
I know it would be something like we do with regular expressions in other languages.But i have no idea how to do this in Mysql.
I source the function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000);
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1);
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN
  loop_label: LOOP
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END$$
```

I tried this:

```
update testplans set tc_name=regex_replace('.*/','',tc_path);
```

It should have given me tc_name=d if tc_path=/a/b/c/d
But instead it gave me abcd.
Am i using a wrong function or i don't know how to use it.
Please suggest some query for it.

Please help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *THIS* particular case, where you are trying to get the last part of a path, you can skip regex and use simple string functions:

```
update testplans set tc_name=substr(tc_path, length(tc_path)-locate('/',reverse(tc_path))+2);
```

Doing search in reverse order

The proper regex expression would be

```
.*/([^/]*)
```

But you'd need to extract the last part, which MySQL really doesn't do. MariaDB 10 has a REGEXP_REPLACE that might help.

Answer (score 0):

The function you have above will replace single characters that match a regex, but it's not a full regular expression replacement. Basically, wrong function.

Mysql isn't great at this right now -- you might want to consider another path, like the one that Jacques suggested, with a simple string replace.

If you really want a regex solution, maybe look at a more complete regex library for mysql:
https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

Comment: Can't i use this function to serve my purpose in anyway?

Comment: You want to replace multiple characters at once.This function replaces single characters. The only single character that can match the pattern `.*/` is `/`, so the outcome is that the slashes get replaced, as you've found.